# Interactive messages on slack without external service

Tags: slack, slack-api

I'm working on a simple slack bot which is supposed to ask simple questions (yes/no) and based on answers perform some actions. AFAIU I should be using interactive messages for this. The problem is that it's supposed that slack will then call some external URL with the result, but for security reasons, I can't expose any service externally.

I was hoping I can just receive some event (using Events API) from Slack that user choose one of the options and simply read it directly using API. Unfortunately I can't find anything like that.

Is possible to use interactive messages without exposing external service to the world?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. If you build a bot with the [Real Time Messaging API](https://api.slack.com/rtm) you do not need to expose an endpoint to the public Internet.

With the RTM API you open a connection to Slack (which can be from behind a firewall) and maintain that connection. There is no call-back from Slack.

However, the RTM API will only enable you to create a chat bot that can react to events and message posts. The interactive message features like buttons and drop-down menus still require you to provide an endpoint.